# Submit button not working because of formating

Tags: javascript, php, sql, arrays

I have been working to get this code working for a little while and finally got it to work by implementing two codes together. Except the formatting of it does not let my submit button work. My submit button acts a save by updating all data entered into the textboxes in a sql database. So this button is absolutely necessary. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong.

```
<?php
mysql_connect("localhost", "username", "password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("databas")or die("cannot bselect DB"); 


$sql="SELECT * FROM test"; 
$result=mysql_query($sql); 

// Count table rows 
$count=mysql_num_rows($result); 
?> 
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="../../favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/normalize.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/styles.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/component.css" />
<script src="javafile.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="component">

            <table class="overflow-y">

                <thead>
                    <tr>
<th width="16%" align="center"  id="box_header2" style='width:10%'><button class="logout"><a href="../login.php?status=loggedout">Log out</a></button>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Name</th>
<th width="16%" align="center" id="box_header2" style='width:10%'>Job Code</th>
<th width="16%" align="center"  id="box_header2" style='width:10%'>Date</th>
<th width="14%" align="center" id="box_header2" style='width:20%'>Address</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<?php 
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($result)){ 
?> 
<form action="update3.php" method="post" name="form1">
<tbody>
<tr> 
<th>
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="Name" value="<? echo $rows['Name'];?>">
</th>
<td>
<input name="job[]" type="text" id="Job" value="<? echo $rows['Job']; ?>">
</td>
<td>
<input name="date[]" type="text" id="Date" value="<? echo $rows['Date']; ?>">
</td>
<td>
<input name="address[]" type="text" id="Address" value="<? echo $rows['Address']; ?>">
</td>
<td>
<input name="id[]" type="hidden" value="<? echo $rows['ID']; ?>">
</td> 
</tr> 
</tbody>
<?php 
} 
?> 
<tr> 

</tr>
</tbody>
<tbody>
<tr>  
<td>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Save">
</td>
</tr> 
</tbody>
</table> 
</td> 
</tr> 
</form> 
</table> 
<?php 
mysql_close();  
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

try this hope it works for you :

```
<input name="name[]" type="text" id="Name" value='<?php echo $rows["uname"];?>'>
```

Comment: They have a lot more than that.

Comment: `<?` isn't a syntax error, it's [**short open**](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php) tag syntax.

Comment: yes @Fred-ii- but they have enclosed the expression in double quote  and that were not getting evaluated i think.

Comment: I doubt that is what the OP's issue is, otherwise OP would have responded to [`my comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26064290/submit-button-not-working-because-of-formating/26064499?noredirect=1#comment40836019_26064290) about short open tags.

Comment: @Fred-ii- i tried in google chrome but short open tag is not working. is it browser dependent?

Comment: No, it is server-side. It's a setting that's changed inside the `php.ini` file. Consult **http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php**

Comment: the short open tag does not affect it at all. without the css and js added on it updates to sql just fine

Answer (score 0):

Please, put the `<form>` tag **before** the `while` loop, otherwise you'll have as many opened forms as rows in the query's result set.

Comment: I tend to think that that would make sense. Let's see what the OP has to say.

Comment: I changed that and it made no difference what so ever